# Ionic 2: Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator (running in emulator)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, camera, ionic2

I just set up my first ionic 2 app (I've used ionic 1 fairly extensively). I'm trying to use the [ionic-native camera](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/camerapreview/) preview plugin.

**The setup was pretty straight forward:**

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
ionic start timesnap --v2
ionic platform add android
ionic platform add ios
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera-preview --save
```

**Then I copied and pasted the example code into the about page:**

```
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewRect } from 'ionic-native';

// camera options (Size and location)
let cameraRect: CameraPreviewRect = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  width: 200,
  height: 200
};


// start camera
CameraPreview.startCamera(
  cameraRect, // position and size of preview
  'front', // default camera
  true, // tap to take picture
  false, // disable drag
  true, // send the preview to the back of the screen so we can addoverlaying elements
  1 //alpha
);
```

**I launched the app using the following commands:**

```
ionic emulate android -lcs

ionic emulate ios -lcs --target='iPhone-6'
```

At first the camera just wasn't showing up then I ran `chrome://inspect` and saw warnings about Cordova missing "try running in an emulator", but this was while running in an android emulator. I tried iOS too and saw the same results.

Any ideas why cordova isn't loading?

Here is the full error log from `chrome://inspect` while running in an android emulator:

[image]

**Update... index.html**

(it's just the standard one generated by ionic)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app class="trans"></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your index.html file as well, particularly where you're including all the necessary scripts?

Comment: @KerriShotts I added it. I figured out that if I don't use the live reload flag (`-l`) it seems to work fine. Not sure if that's expected or not, but I filed an issue on their github. If this is expected it should probably be in the docs somewhere.

Comment: can you check if this is working or not..I want to build the app on change as i am working with native features. Running the `run` command every time is very frustrating..Is livereload working now?

Comment: try this one  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The livereload plugin fails to serve cordova.js file and serves // mock cordova file during development.

FIX: You need go to node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/dev-server/serve-config.js

and replace

```
exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATH = path.join('platforms', 'android', 'assets', 'www');
```

to

```
exports.ANDROID_PLATFORM_PATH = path.join('platforms', 'android', 'app', 'src', 'main', 'assets', 'www');
```

Comment: That worked for me! Anyone know if is there a bug report for that?

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Comment: Worked, thanks. Issue occurred for me with ionic version: 3.20.0

Comment: This works the first time I run, but always fails with the OP error on live reload. Anyone else seeing this behavior?

Comment: `app-scripts` folder is not available in version 4

Comment: That worked for me on ionic 3 with live reload on Adroid device.

Answer (score 160):

This is quite late but anyone going through the same problem might benefit from this answer.First try to add browser by running below command
`ionic platform add browser` and then run command `ionic run browser`.

> **which is the difference between `ionic serve and ionic run browser`?**
>
> Ionic serve - runs your app as a website (meaning it doesn't have any
>   Cordova capabilities). 
>   Ionic run browser - runs your app in the Cordova
>   browser platform, which will inject cordova.js and any plugins that
>   have browser capabilities

You can refer [this link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/403) to know more difference between `ionic serve` and `ionic run browser` command

**Update**

From Ionic 3 this command has been changed. Use the command below instead;

`ionic cordova platform add browser`

`ionic cordova run browser`

You can find out which version of ionic you are using by running: `ionic --version`

Comment: for future references the commands have been changed to, ionic cordova run, ionic cordova add.

Comment: Changing the HTML isn't watched. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: ```ionic cordova run browser``` This command worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: `ionic capacitor run` if you are using capacitor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles with this problem again, the accepted solution did work for older versions of ionic and app scripts, I had used it many times in the past, but last week, after I updated some stuff, it got broken again, and this fix wasn't working anymore as this was already solved on the current version of app-scripts, most of the info is referred on this post https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cordova-run-android-livereload-cordova-not-available/116790/18 but I'll make it short here:

First make sure you have this versions on your system

> cli packages: (xxxx\npm\node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
> Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Node : v10.1.0
> npm  : 5.6.0
> ```

An this on your package.json

> "@angular/cli": "^6.0.3",
>   "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.9",
>   "typescript": "~2.4.2"

Now remove your platform with ionic cordova platform rm what-ever
Then DELETE the node_modules and plugins folder and MAKE SURE the platform was deleted inside the platforms folder.

Finally, run

npm install
ionic cordova platform add what-ever
ionic cordova run

And everything should be working again

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error using the bellow i get it from [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1289#issuecomment-355314622)

`ionic cordova run browser` will load those native plugins that support `browser` platform.

Answer (score -4):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {
  sendObj = {
    to: '',
    cc: '',
    bcc: '',
    attachments:'',
    subject:'',
    body:''
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private emailComposer: EmailComposer) {}

  sendEmail(){
  let email = {
    to: this.sendObj.to,
    cc: this.sendObj.cc,
    bcc: this.sendObj.bcc,
    attachments: [this.sendObj.attachments],
    subject: this.sendObj.subject,
    body: this.sendObj.body,
    isHtml: true
  }; 
  this.emailComposer.open(email);
  }  
 }

starts here html about

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Send Invoice
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>To</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="sendObj.to"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>CC</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="sendObj.cc"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>BCC</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="sendObj.bcc"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Add pdf</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="sendObj.attachments" type="file"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Subject</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="sendObj.subject"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Text message</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="sendObj.body"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <button ion-button full (click)="sendEmail()">Send Email</button>

</ion-content>


other stuff here

import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    EmailComposer,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},  
    File,
    FileOpener
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Comment: What are you trying to tell, please be more descriptive

Answer (score -4):

I also had this same problem.

I build .apk file of the project and installed it into mobile(android) and got it working

Comment: How this relevant to the question, could you explain and add more details?