# Ionic Cordova is not available with livereload on Device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When creating a new app (`ionic start AppTest`), and i try to use `ionic cordova run android -lc`, i get the following error message:

```
console.warn: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
console.warn: Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

My environment is:

cli packages: (C:\Users\marci\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6-201712271536
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.9.3
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : d:\AndroidSdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Cordova Requirements:

Requirements check results for android:

```
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
```

**I've already been trying to solve this problem for 4 days**

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors.

Comment: @luisenrike , are actually errors because the app is unable to access any cordova plugin

Comment: See workaround related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266685/1736679