# "Cordova is not available" even when running app in device

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I'm running my application with the following command in the device

```
ionic cordova run android -l -c
```

It doesn't get cordova.js which I think it should get. So none my plugin works on my device in this mode "-l -c". And when I run following command

```
ionic cordova run android
```

It gets cordova js and all plugins work properly.
What is this weird issue? Please help!

Comment: After a lot of research, I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266685