# Ionic 3 - Cordova unavailable when ran on a device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I want to use some Ionic Native plugins, but I can't quite test them.

Here is code:

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    rootPage:any = 'LoginPage';
    
    constructor(private push: Push, platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
            // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();

            // Add Push Notifications
            push.hasPermission().then((response: any) => {
                if (response.isEnabled) {
                    console.info("Push notification permission granted");
                } else {
                    console.error("Push notifications permission needed");
                }
            });
        });
    }
    
}
```

When I run `ionic cordova run android -l -c --device`, I get the following logs:

> [13:39:15] console.warn: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
>
> [13:39:15] console.warn: Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

And in the app :

> Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available

`this.platform.is('cordova')` is `false` (same as `this.platform.is('android')`)

Specifying `--device` should make cordova available right? Even with `--emulator` I get the same error.
So, **what's wrong ?**

Here is my `ionic info`:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Pierre\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:
    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.9.4
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10
```

And my `ionic cordova plugin --list`:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.2 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-ionic 4.0.0 "IonicCordova"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.2 "PushPlugin"
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a new blank Ionic project and running `ionic cordova run android -l -c --device`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check you have cordova.js included in the index.html? And if so, is it loading before the other scripts?

```
<!-- Ionic's root component andionic cordova platform remove ios where the app will load -->
<ion-app></ion-app>

<!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

<!-- all code from node_modules directory is here -->
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

<!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
<script src="build/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, cordova.js is in the `<head>` tag while main.js is at the end of the `<body>`

Comment: Is it working without live reload? If so, this is probably your fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266685

Answer (score 0):

Try to run without the livereload ( -l ), sometimes you don't have the grants with the livereload option:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```