# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available with ionic serve

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I know that cordova plugins are not available with `ionic serve` and I always check if I am in a cordova Environment before trying to use a cordova plugin.

After saying that. I do not know why I am getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at rejected (main.js:1469)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1448
21:23:35.110
```

I am not sure how it started, I think it had something to do with the [`ionic livereload` workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266685/1255819) but I had updated my app-scripts versions and reinstalled all the `node_modules`, `plugins` and `platforms` and the problem stills persist.

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Saninn.000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.11.0
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\distante\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.my.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>my App</name>

    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#1FBBA5" />
    <preference name="HeaderColor" value="#008B80" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="27" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-headsetdetection" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-market" spec="^1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-music-controls" spec="^2.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="^2.6.2" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="^0.14.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-headercolor" spec="^1.0.0" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
</widget>
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/header-color": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/market": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/music-controls": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/animejs": "^2.0.0",
    "animejs": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.15.1",
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.15.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-headercolor": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-headsetdetection": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-music-controls": "^2.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.6.2",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "device": "^0.3.9",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-music-controls": {},
      "cordova-plugin-headsetdetection": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "cordova-plugin-market": {},
      "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-headercolor": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_purge_unused_fonts": false,
    "ionic_uglifyjs": "./config/uglifyjs.config.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be because you called a native function before checking if platform is ready in the app.ts file. Can you check that?

Comment: I checked and all my native calls are made after platform ready (sorry I was away this hole time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the comment from @toby-okeke about calling native plugins before `platform.ready` I rechecked my code and all was correctly done BUT looks like the `statusBar` and `appVersion` plugins does not behave correctly when there is no `cordova.js`. While other plugins show a warning like:

> Native: tried calling PluginName.prepare, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

`statusBar` and `appVersion` throw the error from my question. I wrapped them in a `if(this.platform.is("cordova"))` and the error is gone.