# ionic phone gap navigator map does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Native: tried calling LaunchNavigator.navigate, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

```
cordovaWarn @ util.js:66
checkAvailability @ plugin.js:24
callCordovaPlugin @ plugin.js:113
(anonymous) @ plugin.js:142
(anonymous) @ util.js:22
t @ polyfills.js:3
tryNativePromise @ util.js:21
getPromise @ util.js:29
wrapPromise @ plugin.js:125
(anonymous) @ plugin.js:279
value @ decorators.js:132
webpackJsonp.98.HomePage.navigate @ home.ts:124
(anonymous) @ HomePage.ngfactory.js:258
handleEvent @ core.js:13589
handleEvent @ core.js:14321
dispatchEvent @ core.js:10004
(anonymous) @ core.js:10629
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:2628
globalListener @ platform-browser.js:3196
home.ts:127 Error launching navigator cordova_not_available


let options: LaunchNavigatorOptions = {
  start: 'London, ON',
  // app: LaunchNavigator.APPS.UBER
};

this.launchNavigator.navigate('Toronto, ON', options)
  .then(
    success => console.log('Launched navigator'),
    error => console.log('Error launching navigator', error)
  );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7OP8.png)

Comment: I tried  to both

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2: Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator (running in emulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815183/ionic-2-cordova-is-not-available-make-sure-to-include-cordova-js-or-run-in-a-d)

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: please check above question. That is same as yours. Hope it will help you